# System.QueryException: unexpected token: results

Tags: apex

I am running an apex test and getting the following error:

```
System.QueryException: unexpected token: results
```

What I do not understand is that I am running this query in another one of my classes and it works perfectly. The only difference is that this query includes a group by clause. Not sure why the grouping would initiate this error? Is this because I am using a group by within a dynamic soql call?

```
 String contactsWorked_lastWeek  = 'SELECT count(id) results, account.SDR_Owner__c SDR results from contact where LastActivityDate = last_week AND account.RecordTypeid != \'0126A000000ytERQAY\' group by account.SDR_Owner__c';

lastWeek_queries.add(contactsWorked_lastWeek);

List<AggregateResult> contactsWorked_lastWeek = Database.query(queries[0]);
```

VS

```
String contactsWorked_lastWeek  = 'select count(id) results from contact where LastActivityDate = last_week AND account.RecordTypeid != \'0126A000000ytERQAY\'';

 lastWeek_queries.add(contactsWorked_lastWeek);

List<AggregateResult> contactsWorked_lastWeek = Database.query(queries[0]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Query #1:

```
'SELECT count(id) results, account.SDR_Owner__c SDR results from contact where LastActivityDate = last_week AND account.RecordTypeid != \'0126A000000ytERQAY\' group by account.SDR_Owner__c';
```

has a double alias:

```
account.SDR_Owner__c SDR results
```

remove the spurious word "results" here and this one should work.

Query #2:

... is fine, because it's a `count()` query. Please excuse my brain-slippage.